# Asus N551JK and no. of external monitors

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, asus-laptop

How many external monitors can the notebook Asus n551jk cn104d support?

The notebook has a geforce 850m graphics card with alternate intel hd graphics

It has one HDMI and one mini display port, but I'm unable to find out if it can run both of them as well as the main display at the same time thus achieving a 3 monitor combo.

Essentially the HDMI would be used for a TV, the display port for an external monitor both full hd.

Would there be noticeable performance issues even if it does support all of them (for average usage)?

Answer (score 1):

I have one too :-)

Tested with a AOC 23 inch DP monitor and a LG HDMI monitor. The notebook was able to drive them both, together with the internal display at Full HD resolution. Windows 8 runs still very smoothly with this configuration. I even use the configuration more than my i7-3770 desktop after I discovered that it worked so well.

It also has DP 1.2 so in theory it should be able to drive even 3 monitors on the mini DP output. But I think you won't be able to use the internal display in that case.

So don't worry!